# Windows batch file echo all file paths in directory to file with special characters

Tags: batch-file

So I've been trying to write a script than can echo all the file paths of all files in a directory (including subdirectories).

I've come up with this so far:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "delims=" %%F IN ('dir /b /s /B *.java') do (
    SET "str123=%%~F"
    echo "!str123:\=/!" >> sources.txt
)
```

This works as I want it to except for situations where the file paths contain special characters such as 'º'. When this particular situation happens the character in the .txt file is replaced by a '§'. Attempting to run javac for this source file will then fail (it says the file is missing). If I open the text file and replace all § by 'º' it will work.
Is there any way to improve my script to handle these situations?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with FOR /F - It does not handle unicode characters that do not map to the current code page.

But FOR /R does work :-)

In the off chance that a file name could contain `!`, you should toggle delayed expansion on and off within your loop. FOR variables containing `!` are corrupted upon expansion if delayed expansion is enabled.

Your code reopens the output file once for each iteration. It takes time to open and position the write cursor. Performance is significantly better if you surround the entire FOR statement in an extra set of parentheses and only redirect once. This also allows you to use normal redirection (not append mode), so your output file can start out empty each time.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
(for /r %%F in (*.java) do (
  set "file=%%F"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  echo "!file:\=/!"
  endlocal
)) >sources.txt
```

The only disadvantage of using FOR /R instead of FOR /F with DIR /S is that you cannot get system or hidden files this way. But your original code was not getting system or hidden files anyway.

For future reference, you can include system and hidden files with the DIR command if you use `dir /a`. Using `/a` without any attributes causes DIR to accept all attributes.

Comment: I tried copy pasting that script and running it and the 'º' still got replaced by '§' (consequently leading to javac not compiling). Perhaps I'm doing something wrong?